# Cannot get environment kernel to work with Jupyter notebook to use geopandas

Tags: jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda many times.  I have tried:
Installing geopandas directly into the base (hangs, will not install)
Installing geopandas into the geo_env environment (works, but will not activate on the Jupyter kernel)

(By the way, I have also tried the microcondas environment and rolling back to the windows 32 bit environment, neither worked.)

Here's where I am now, and I am stumped:
[Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IECg.png)

I read the part about the Linking Jupyter kernelspec to Anaconda Python #2898 and it looks okay, picture below. https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2898
[kernel.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcZZi.png)

Which results in this: [Disconnected kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj3IG.png)